# Extract multiple values using regex and reformat them into a new string in a shell oneliner?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, posix

Lets say for a simple example that I have a bunch of lines like this:

```
(1,2)
(3,4)
```

And I want to transform them into something like this:

```
second value: 2; first value: 1
second value: 4; first value: 3
```

In general I want to extract those values using a regex and then use them as variables for formatting an output string.

Can this be done in a shell oneliner using sed/awk or something similar?

Comment: yes it can be done with sed/awk.. but we need to see the code where you got stuck

Comment: `I want to extract those values using a regex` - why do you want to use a regexp? [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one `s` command:

```
sed 's/(\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\))/second value: \2; first value: \1/' file
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
awk -F'[\\(\\),]' '{print "second value: "$3"; first value: "$2}'
```

That is delimiting each row by either a "(", ")", or ",". Then it just prints out the 3rd and 2nd values found (your two numbers).

Comment: `()` are not special inside `[]`, no need to escape them

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` to remove the parentheses, then print whatever's on each side of the `,` in the desired order:

```
sed 's/[()]//g;s/\(.*\),\(.*\)/second value: \2; first value: \1/' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

another `sed` with `rev`

```
$ rev file | sed 's/)/second value: /;s/,/; first value: /;s/(//'

second value: 2; first value: 1
second value: 4; first value: 3
```